# How to move to next Item of a ListView using a Button

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, listview

I want to move the selection to the next Item of a ListView, using a Button.
I need to deselect the Item currently selected and select the one below it.
I tried this code but it's not working as expected:

```
ListView1.Items(ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Index + 1).Selected = True
ListView1.Items(ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Index + 1).EnsureVisible()
ListView1.Focus()
ListView1.Select()
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain things in less vague terms than "go to" the next item. Do you mean move focus from one item to the one below it? Deselect an item and select the one below it? Something else? I'm guessing that you're talking about selection, based on your code, but we shouldn't have to guess.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Dear jmcilhinney,  Deselect an item and select the one below it, this is exactly what I want.I updated my questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select the previous or next Item of a ListView, you can take into consideration the index of returned by the first element of the [SelectedIndices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindices) collection.
If this collection is empty, you can assume this index is `0`.
Clear the current selection, using `SelectedItems.Clear()`, then increment or decrement this index by `1`, verifying that the new index doesn't fall outside the bounds of the `Items` collection.

The [EnsureVisible()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.ensurevisible) method brings into view the selected item if it's not currently visible (it's outside the ListView client area).

Since you're using Buttons to change the selected Item and setting the  [ListView.HideSelection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.hideselection) property to `False` may not have the desired *visual effect*, you may also want to focus your ListView, since clicking a Button steals the Focus from other Controls (unless the Button itself is not selectable).

Assume you have a ListView named `Listview1` and two Buttons, named `btnPrevious` and `btnNext`, used to move the selection to the previous and next Item:

```
Private Sub btnPrevious_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrevious.Click
    Dim itemSelected As Integer = GetListViewSelectedItemIndex(ListView1)
    itemSelected += If(itemSelected > 0, -1, 0)
    SetListViewSelectedItem(ListView1, itemSelected)
End Sub

Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    Dim itemSelected As Integer = GetListViewSelectedItemIndex(ListView1)
    itemSelected += If(itemSelected < ListView1.Items.Count - 1, 1, 0)
    SetListViewSelectedItem(ListView1, itemSelected)
End Sub

Private Function GetListViewSelectedItemIndex(lv As ListView) As Integer
    Return If(lv.SelectedItems.Count > 0, lv.SelectedIndices(0), 0)
End Function

Private Sub SetListViewSelectedItem(lv As ListView, index As Integer)
    If lv.Items.Count = 0 Then Return
    lv.SelectedItems.Clear()
    If Not lv.Focused Then lv.Focus()
    lv.EnsureVisible(index)
    lv.Items(index).Selected = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It may seem simple, but have you tried :

```
    ListView1.SelectedIndex = ListView1.SelectedIndex + 1
```

Also, don't forget the iteration where the selected item is the last one in the list, so that you can move on to the first one.